# EV tax rebate based on previous year (2023) income for a non resident. Moved to the US in 2024 but had US income < 150K in 2023. Filed 1040NR

Tags: income-tax

I am planning to buy an EV in the next few days.

My situation

**2023 - I was a Canadian resident with US income (under the 150K limit) through company stocks.** Will file the 2023 taxes (1040NR) next week similar to what I have done for the last few years.

**2024 - Moved to the US in Jan and will be a resident for 2024 with US income > 150K** and will buy the car with POS credit. I think I will be eligible for the tax credit based on my 2023 AGI in the US through 1040NR even though I wasn't a resident.

IRS states that you can use your Adjusted Gross Income (AGI) from the current year (2024) or the previous year (2023) whichever is lower. In my case 2023 US income is under 150K but 2024 is over 150K. **Does it matter if you were a resident of another country in 2023 but had US income, filed 1040NR and use that income (under 150k) to claim the EV tax rebate at POS in 2024 where my 2024 income will be more than 150k?**

Thanks in advance for any help.